# Can we run multiprocessing Pool in GAE?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, multiprocessing

Is it possible to run multiprocessing Pool in gae?

If yes, how come my code runs fine in my local machine but pops out the following err msg with django remote api:

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 148, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()   
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 422, in get
    raise self._value TypeError: __init__() keywords must be strings
```

Comment: The development SDK environment doesn't even weakly attempt to ensure that your local machine will only run things that run on Google's App Engine servers. So it should never be a big surprise if something fancy that worked locally does not work when deployed to Google App Engine, particularly when its use is not mentioned in any SDK docs.

If you need to do "background work" on App Engine, you may be interested in task queues:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/

Comment: @Sasha Yes it does. The only reason multiprocessing works in the dev_appserver is because it's a feature introduced in 2.5, and the OP is running 2.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to run multiprocessing on the production servers, but if you are using the remote_api, then you can run your script locally (with multiprocessing) and have each Pool process use communicate with the production server via remote_api calls.

If you need `multiprocess` style actions actually in server-side code, then the Mapper API is perfect for this task.

Comment: Or more likely, the Task Queue API.